# Call a backend function from flask web app getting access violation for file open function

Tags: python, flask, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a flask function which is like below. When I trigger this via an html, the function named (function_to_be_called) does not work properly cause it uses a library (prolog) which opens a file (prolog config file).

I am getting OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000050

When I call this function directly, without the web interface everything is ok.

I need help in executing the function and getting the results.
Kind Regards,
Ferda

```
@app.route("/execute_scenario/", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def executeScenario():
    form = IndexForm(request.form)
    input1 = "something"
    input2 = 5678
    function_to_be_called(inpt1, input2)
 return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

Comment: Is the `pool` code meant to be part of your `executeScenario` function? It's not indented, so the code as written above seems wrong. Also, what is `function_to_be_called`? That seems like necessary information. Lastly, just FYI, you talk about multithreading but your example uses multiprocessing, which is a different thing.

Comment: Hi, I know multithreating and multiprocessing are different. I took this code sample from some example and modified it. I think what I try to do it very clear, but let me redescribe. I just want to call a function named function_to_be_called which takes two input variables. The pool related code came from the prolog web site where they suggested to use this pool structure to overcome the access violation error.

Comment: If you can suggest any correction, please do.. If you say the pool is not right to be used here, you may suggest another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to PrologMQI. Now the problem is solved.